# zero to standard issue in any view's constraints

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ios13, swift5

when I add **constraints** in Xcode **add new constraints**, all my 0 and negative 0 turns into standard and it gives some strange output when I set those constraints. How can I fix this?

Is this any new feature of Xcode or issue I don't know?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

---

This is an **issue** from Xcode and they will resolve it in the next update. **Beta version** of this update is available on the [Apple's website](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode_release_notes/xcode_11_4_beta_release_notes)

They have fixed a bug that prevented entering a 0 constant in the constraint popup editors. (54076090)

---